# How to fetch the user name of user browsing the site in asp.net core 2.0 web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is my home controller code

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IApiHelper apiHelper;
        private GetFormHelper helper;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        ILogger logger;

        public HomeController(IApiHelper _apiHelper,IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,ILogger _logger)
        {
            apiHelper = _apiHelper;
            helper = new GetFormHelper(apiHelper);
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            logger = _logger;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("role")))
            {
                var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1]; //This is returning username but when i deploy to IIS, its returning application name instead of user name
                //var userId = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);



                HttpContext.Session.SetString("userName", userName);

                
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Startup.cs code

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

This is returning username

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
```

but when i deploy to IIS, its returning application name instead of user name,So i used HttpContextAccessor,

```
var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

but this is returning null, how to fetch the user name, it has to work when deployed to IIS, I'm using application pool identity for the application pool. Turned off anonymous authentication and turned on windows authentication for the site in IIS

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: yes, i get the error object reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: Can you show your `launchSettings.json` settings?

Comment: My bad, i was not aware that launchSettings file needs to modified to enable windows and disable anonymous authentication, it did the trick, thanks

Comment: I'll write an elaborated answer with people with the same problem who might check this post in a near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're using Windows Authentication, you need to enable it and disable Anonymous Authentication from your `launchsettings.json` file on the iisSettings section.

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": true,
"anonymousAuthentication": false,
 //Rest of your config
  }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to retrieve your user info, in this case, the username, you have to call `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
var userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

In the launchSetting.Json file

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

This link helped me
https://thecodebuzz.com/get-current-user-name-asp-net-core/